# Which database management system should I use for this task?

Tags: nosql, hierarchical-data

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujcMb.jpg)
I need to choose a hierarchical database management system for my project, which hierarchical database management system would you advise me to use? Thank you in advance. Thank you

haven't tried anything yet.